# Trying to run appium test case through android studio getting error

Tags: android, appium

trying to run appium testcase from android studio.I have added the jars and dependecies but I am getting following error when i run the test case:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:89)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:63)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:58)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
        at com.fieldforce.test.testSample.setUp(testSample.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.auth.Credentials
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 24 more


    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.fieldforce.test.testSample.tearDown(testSample.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
```

Comment: use IntellijIdea and maven is better

Comment: was a jar version error. It's working fine now.